# Any performance issues were using maximum number of pages from stackedwidget in qt framework

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

In QT Framework, Stacked Widget container we are using, In that we can use maximum number of pages above 50 pages which was lot of widgets grid layouts and buttons.. If we use like this means **we get any performance issues of stacked widget in QT**??? or 
*else we have to use other method of using multiple pages in single application.*

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to try it and see; performance will vary a lot depending on what computer and OS you're running on, what kind of widgets you are using, and so on.  My guess is that once all your 50 pages have been set up, you'll run okay, but it might take a long time (e.g. several seconds) to do that initial setup/population of 50 page's worth of widgets and buttons.

Comment: HI Jeremy, ARM 32 bit with Linux OS - Embedded Device, So initially loaded with stacked widget approach of more than 50 pages in this container. **it is nice to move on (or) have to see better approach.** If we go this device means we will get any performance issues???

Comment: Write a test program that behaves roughly like your actual app will behave.  Run it.  Observe its performance.  Nobody else can do that for you.  I could say "yes" or "no" but why you should trust my say-so?  I'm just some random person on the Internet and could well be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a performance issue, only the currently active widget is being rendered. It could be a memory issue though, as the widgets, even if not visible, will still reside in memory. If your embedded platform is modest on RAM you definitely don't want to keep non-visible widgets in memory, the CPU outta be fast enough to handle the actual work.

The memory problem can be avoided by decoupling logic from GUI completely, then you can only have the logic in memory, which should be much more compact, and only create the view widgets when necessary and destroy when not needed, this way you can preserve the dialog state without keeping the actual dialog in memory, just its data.

Also, don't get lost in premature optimizations. You don't have a problem until you empirically establish that you do.